# Laravel Fortify redirects after login, but doesn't login user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, fortify

I am trying to make a simple authentication system using Fortify. My frontend is react JS. I tried fortify basic features a week ago and everything was working well. But now that I try it nothing works. To be specific:

- After sending a POST request to /auth/login fortify redirects me to / as if I have been logged in but when I do Auth::check() it gives false. I also tried it through Postman, the same thing happens
- Registering a person works. It makes a new entry in the database and redirects to /. But it also doesn't log in the use

I have tried a lot of thing to fix this(reverted all the changes because they didn't work):

- changed guard and middleware in fortify.php
- changed available features
- reinstalled fortify
- created my own Fortify::authenticateUsing()
- tried removing all other paths
  Nothing worked

Extra notes:

- the Route::get('/{path?}',  ... is for all routes to route to a react app

fortify.php

```
<?php

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;

return [

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Fortify Guard
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here you may specify which authentication guard Fortify will use while
   | authenticating users. This value should correspond with one of your
   | guards that is already present in your "auth" configuration file.
   |
   */

   'guard' => 'web',

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Fortify Password Broker
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here you may specify which password broker Fortify can use when a user
   | is resetting their password. This configured value should match one
   | of your password brokers setup in your "auth" configuration file.
   |
   */

   'passwords' => 'users',

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Username / Email
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | This value defines which model attribute should be considered as your
   | application's "username" field. Typically, this might be the email
   | address of the users but you are free to change this value here.
   |
   | Out of the box, Fortify expects forgot password and reset password
   | requests to have a field named 'email'. If the application uses
   | another name for the field you may define it below as needed.
   |
   */

   'username' => 'email',

   'email' => 'email',

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Home Path
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here you may configure the path where users will get redirected during
   | authentication or password reset when the operations are successful
   | and the user is authenticated. You are free to change this value.
   |
   */

   'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME,

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Fortify Routes Prefix / Subdomain
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here you may specify which prefix Fortify will assign to all the routes
   | that it registers with the application. If necessary, you may change
   | subdomain under which all of the Fortify routes will be available.
   |
   */

   'prefix' => 'auth',

   'domain' => null,

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Fortify Routes Middleware
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here you may specify which middleware Fortify will assign to the routes
   | that it registers with the application. If necessary, you may change
   | these middleware but typically this provided default is preferred.
   |
   */

   'middleware' => ['web'],

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Rate Limiting
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | By default, Fortify will throttle logins to five requests per minute for
   | every email and IP address combination. However, if you would like to
   | specify a custom rate limiter to call then you may specify it here.
   |
   */

   'limiters' => [
       'login' => 'login',
       'two-factor' => 'two-factor',
   ],

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Register View Routes
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here you may specify if the routes returning views should be disabled as
   | you may not need them when building your own application. This may be
   | especially true if you're writing a custom single-page application.
   |
   */

   'views' => false,

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Features
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Some of the Fortify features are optional. You may disable the features
   | by removing them from this array. You're free to only remove some of
   | these features or you can even remove all of these if you need to.
   |
   */

   'features' => [
       Features::registration(),
       Features::resetPasswords(),
       // Features::emailVerification(),
       Features::updateProfileInformation(),
       Features::updatePasswords(),
       Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
           'confirmPassword' => true,
       ]),
   ],

];
```

FortifyServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->email.$request->ip());
        });

        RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
        });
    }
}
```

Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/{path?}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('path', '.*')->middleware('auth');
```

Code for testing from react app

```
    const Login = () =>
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/auth/login',
        data: {
          email: 'leon@gmail.com',
          password: 'password'
        }
      }).then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

APIController for checking if user is logged in

```
    public function checkIfLoggedIn(){
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged in']);
        }
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Not logged in']);
    }
```

I have been trying to fix this for 3 hours now, any help is appreciated. Thank you
If you need any more of the code the here is the github repo : https://github.com/LeonLav77/M-Store.git

Answer (score 2):

I guess somewhere in the process of middleware I removed the ability to start sessions the fix is to add

\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class

to kernel php

```
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller function you can try the way I know:

```
public function checkIfLoggedIn(Request $request) {
   // with this you can get the info of the user logged in
   // $loggedUser = auth()->user();
   // check from $request->user() if auth()->user() not working
   $message = ( $request->user() ) ? ['message' => 'Logged In'] : ['message' => 
              'Not Logged In'];
   return response()->json($message);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the output is still the same :/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this problem, after some digging I found [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authuser-returns-null-value) something that helped me — If you change the ID field of the `Users` table to other thing than big integer, it will fail the authentication.

My migration file looked something like this:

```php
Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // I wanted to use a UUID.
    $table->uuid()->default(DB::raw("(UUID())"));
    // ...
});
```

Just did this, launched a fresh migration and everything worked as expected.

```php
Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Just added this.
    $table->id();
    // I wanted to use a UUID.
    $table->uuid()->default(DB::raw("(UUID())"));
    // ...
});
```